# Canny edge output is corrupted

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, edge-detection, canny-operator

I am applying Canny edge detector in a video using OpenCV. I can see the result in a window and then I am writing the video. Even though I can see the right result on the window, the result in the output file is not the same.

Here is the code and what I can see in the window and in the output file. Any idea what can cause this?
I am not sure what is the output of Canny and if I have to turn it to type of data that will fit with the rest of the video.

```
        `

    import cv2
    import numpy as np


    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('New_video.mp4')
    if (cap.isOpened() == False):
     print("Unable to read camera feed")

     frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
     frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
     fps = int(round(cap.get(5)))
     out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), fps, 
   (frame_width, frame_height))

    while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == False:
    break 
         if between (cap,40000,45000):
           gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
           frame = cv2.blur(gray,(5,5))
           frame = cv2.Canny(frame,20,60)   
         if between (cap,45000,50000):
          gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
          frame = cv2.blur(gray,(5,5))
          frame = cv2.Canny(frame,150,250)` 
       out.write(frame)    
       cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
```

Comment: Where do you write your output and where do you view the window? Please show full code for that.

Comment: I updated the code to show the imshow window and output

Answer (score 0):

Try using XVID fourcc codec instead of mp4v. Also,VideoWriter method has one more parameter **isColor** which is set to be true by default. It should be set to False whenever we use gray scale images.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html